Ubuntu on laptop doesn't go into suspend mode
It seems my laptop can't really go into suspend mode. I can see the power led light is on, and I can hear the cooler works. Seems to work fine on Windows though. Already tried installing proprietary Nvidia drivers but it didn't help. Where should I search for the cause of this issue?
MSI GL66,
6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap space. Read man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab pm-suspend.

@waltinator thanks. I think "suspend" is the default option for Ubuntu and exactly what I need. But the fact that I can hear cooler working means it doesn't actually go in thar state.
